# Connection Reset by Peer Occuring on Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, urllib, alexa-skills-kit

I wrote a simple script in Python 2.7 that compiles my homework off of my school website using urllib(2), cookielib, and bs4. When I ran it off of my IDE it worked perfectly without any errors. However when compile it for Alexa and I run it on AWS Lambda, I receive the following error:

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer: error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 136, in lambda_handler
return on_launch(event['request'], event['session'])
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 80, in on_launch
return scraper(session)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 98, in scraper
open(URL)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in open
return browser.open(url, postdata).read()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1243, in https_open
context=self._context)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1203, in do_open
r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1136, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 453, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 756, in recv
return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 643, in read
v = self._sslobj.read(len)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I know that usually this is because the server I'm attempting to access is dropping the connection, but I can't figure out why it works in my IDE and not in my lambda.

Here is my original code I use in the IDE:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
assignment = []
classes = []
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
browser = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
def open(url, postdata=None):
    if postdata is not None:
        postdata = urllib.urlencode(postdata)
    return browser.open(url, postdata).read()


USER = 'USERNAME' # these aren't my real credentials
PASS = 'PASSWORD'
URL = 'my school homework website'
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

open(URL)

POST = {'username': USER,
        'password': PASS,
        'date': now}

loggedIn = open(URL, POST)
soup = BeautifulSoup(loggedIn, "html.parser")
for span in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'title'}):
    assignment.append(span.get_text())

for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sub', 'style':'white-space: normal;'}):
    classes.append(div.get_text())

for i in range(0, len(assignment)):
    print 'for ', classes[i], 'your homework is ', assignment[i]
```

Here is the Lambda code that throws the error:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
assignment = []
classes = []
final_assignments = []
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
browser = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

def open(url, postdata=None):
    if postdata is not None:
        postdata = urllib.urlencode(postdata)
    return browser.open(url, postdata).read()

USER = 'USERNAME' # Not my actual Credentials
PASS = 'PASSWORD'
URL = 'my school homework website'
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

def build_speechlet_response(title, output, reprompt_text, should_end_session):
    return {
        'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': output
        },
        'card': {
            'type': 'Simple',
            'title': title,
            'content': output
        },
        'reprompt': {
            'outputSpeech': {
                'type': 'PlainText',
                'text': reprompt_text
            }
        },
        'shouldEndSession': should_end_session
    }


def build_response(session_attributes, speechlet_response):
    return {
        'version': '1.0',
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'response': speechlet_response
    }


# --------------- Functions that control the skill's behavior ------------------

def handle_session_end_request():
    card_title = "Session Ended"
    speech_output = "Thank you for using Homework Retriever!"
    # Setting this to true ends the session and exits the skill.
    should_end_session = True
    return build_response({}, build_speechlet_response(
        card_title, speech_output, None, should_end_session))


# --------------- Events ------------------

def on_session_started(session_started_request, session):
    """ Called when the session starts """

    print("on_session_started requestId=" + session_started_request['requestId']
          + ", sessionId=" + session['sessionId'])


def on_launch(launch_request, session):
    """ Called when the user launches the skill without specifying what they
    want
    """

    print("on_launch requestId=" + launch_request['requestId'] +
          ", sessionId=" + session['sessionId'])
    # Dispatch to your skill's launch
    return scraper(session)





def on_session_ended(session_ended_request, session):
    """ Called when the user ends the session.

    Is not called when the skill returns should_end_session=true
    """
    print("on_session_ended requestId=" + session_ended_request['requestId'] +
          ", sessionId=" + session['sessionId'])
    # add cleanup logic here

# --------------- Main handler ------------------
def scraper(session):
    sessionAttributes = session.get('attributes', {})
    open(URL)

    POST = {'username': USER,
            'password': PASS,
            'date': now}
    loggedIn = open(URL, POST)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(loggedIn, "html.parser")
    for span in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'title'}):
        assignment.append(span.get_text())
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sub', 'style':'white-space: normal;'}):
        classes.append(div.get_text())
    for i in range(0, len(assignment)):
        assignment_not_finished = "for " + str(classes[i]) + "your homework is " + str(assignment[i])
        final_assignments.append(str(assignment_not_finished))
    return build_response(sessionAttributes, build_speechlet_response(
        'Your Homework', str(final_assignments), 'null', True))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """ Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest,
    etc.) The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter.
    """
    print("event.session.application.applicationId=" +
          event['session']['application']['applicationId'])

    """
    Uncomment this if statement and populate with your skill's application ID to
    prevent someone else from configuring a skill that sends requests to this
    function.
    """
    # if (event['session']['application']['applicationId'] !=
    #         "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.[unique-value-here]"):
    #     raise ValueError("Invalid Application ID")

    if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId']},
                           event['session'])

    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_session_ended(event['request'], event['session'])
```

Comment: Some organizations, for reasons that generally seem ill-informed, have been occasionally known to block access to their sites from Amazon IP address space.  A connection reset is a somewhat unusual way to do this, but it would be effective.  Have you considered that possibility?  Is this an authorized use of the site in question or do they have AUP terms preventing mechanized access?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Well since I can do it from my IDE I don't think mechanized access is the issue. I SSHed into an AWS EC2 instance and used the curl command to connect to this same website and didn't have any issues so I don't think the Amazon IP is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving:

```py
cj = cookielib.CookieJar() 
browser = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)) 
browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] 

def open(url, postdata=None): 
  if postdata is not None: 
    postdata = urllib.urlencode(postdata) 
    return browser.open(url, postdata).read() 

USER = 'USERNAME' # Not my actual Credentials 
PASS = 'PASSWORD' 
URL = 'my school homework website' 
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

into the scraper function it's working